# Embeddings of the sporadic simple groups

Tags: finite-groups

This is essentially a reference request. According to the classification of the finite simple groups, there are 26 (or arguably 27) sporadic groups. Let us denote these by G_1 , ... , G_{26} (resp. G_{27}).

> **Question**: *Which G_i can be embedded into which G_j?*

I was unable to find the answer to this question in the literature, but I suspect that the experts will know where to look. Note that it is not too difficult to [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_group) a diagram describing the weaker property of "which G_i is a *subquotient* of which G_j."

Comment: this (subquotient) property is weaker but its negation is stronger, and this is information provided by the diagram...

Comment: @YCor : thanks for spotting that. I should have copy-pasted the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_group instead.

Comment: @YCor : done, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Table 2, p. 362 in:

- Wilson, Robert A.
  Is the Suzuki group Sz(8) a subgroup of the Monster? Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 48 (2016), no. 2, 355-364. https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdw012

Which lists all simple groups that are contained in a sporadic group.

It seems the question you ask about (which sporadics can be embedded into another sporadic) was settled in these papers:

- Griess, Robert L., Jr. The friendly giant. Invent. Math. 69 (1982), no. 1, 1-102.   https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01389186
- Wilson, Robert A. Is J1 a subgroup of the Monster? Bull. London Math. Soc. 18 (1986), no. 4, 349-350. https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/18.4.349

Comment: spin : Thank you! That is a wonderfully precise (and quick!) answer to my question =).